# CREATE TABLE AS SELECT has poor performance on vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

We are currently moving our DBMS to vertica, but have problems handling duplicates. In MySQL we simply used `INSERT IGNORE`. Duplicates in our data input stream have to be filtered on the database layer.
I have implemented this by having a `tableName_import` table without constraints which will be used to store all data. Another table `tableName_dedup` houses only data without duplicates.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName_dedup
AS SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM (SELECT *, row_number OVER (PARTITION BY column1, column2)
as rownum FROM tableName_import) import
where import.rownum = 1;
```

The `tableName_import` table houses roughly 1.5 million entries with 2GB of data. The creation of the `tableName_dedup` table takes about 10 minutes.

Is there a way to improve the performance?

**edit: There is one `VARCHAR(50000)` column in the import table. When I remove this column the query runs in a matter of seconds. Why does this one column slow the query down so much?**

Comment: It could quite possibly be simple because your select takes that long. That would be the first thing to confirm. Optimise your select (with indexes) and it'll probably go faster

Comment: Your records are pretty big (over 1k per record).  I'm surprised it takes 10 minutes, but not surprised that the performance is noticeable.  Vertica has to create separate column stores for each column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Do you have an idea how I could improve the performance?

Comment: Without the `CREATE TABLE`, how long does just the `SELECT column1, column2, ... FROM (SELECT *, row_number...` take?

Answer (score 1):

Work with the machine, not against it.

INSERT ... IGNORE is a very specific and un-intuitive type of clause, so few databases support it.

The MERGE command is much more common, and you can just omit the WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE clause, like so:

```
MERGE /*+DIRECT*/ 
INTO  d_teas_scd  t 
USING d_teas_stg  s
   ON s.tea_key = t.tea_key
WHEN NOT matched THEN INSERT (
  tea_key
, tea_id
, tea_eff_dt
, tea_end_dt
, tea_name
, tea_price
) VALUES (
  s.tea_key
, s.tea_id
, s.tea_eff_dt
, s.tea_end_dt
, s.tea_name
, s.tea_price
);
```

And if you want to use OLAP functions - then try the analytic LIMIT clause, which is, I think, unique to Vertica, and goes:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM d_teas_scd
LIMIT 1 OVER(PARTITION BY tea_id ORDER BY tea_eff_dt DESC)
;
```

Pretty efficient ...

Good luck -

Comment: The ```MERGE``` command still causes a duplicate key error. Are you sure this should work?
Sadly the ```LIMIT 1 OVER``` clause does not seem to be faster than the ```row_number()``` version.

Comment: You only run into a duplicate key if the columns in the ON  clause of the MERGE command don't match the unique/ primary key columns of the target table. And I would be pretty sure that, if the analytic limit clause is slow, you have not segmented and sorted the target table correctly. The main projection, for it to run fast, must be, in my case, SEGMENTED BY tea_id ORDER BY tea_eff_dt. (maybe experiment with ... ORDER BY tea_eff_dt DESC ) ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but this is how we handle duplicates.

You could use the COPY TABLE function to copy the table with its contents. This will copy over partition expressions, projections, keys etc.

Once you have done this you can dedupe on the copied table and then use SWAP_PARTITIONS_BETWEEN_TABLES function.

This will swap the partitions from the copied table over with you working table and it is instant. Then all you have to do is drop the copied table.

The only bit that would take a bit of time would be the deduping but you could do a delete including row_number OVER (PARTITION BY column1, column2) to remove the duplicates.

There is a bit more time taken when writing your scripts but it should be significanlty quicker than the CREATE TABLE AS SELECT.

Thanks